# A* algorithm taking too long to solve

Tags: java, path-finding, a-star

I have to use an algorithm to find a path for a school project. I have a sequence of 12 goals on the map, which must be reached before the end of the path. The map is a 70x70 array. What I already did:

## I find all the goals and add in a list

The goals are marked by numbers 10 to 21, and i put on a list 0 to 12. (21 IS THE last goal)

```
private casa[] acharCasas(){
    casa[] casas = new casa[12];
    for (int linha = 0; linha < jogo.getMapa().length; linha++) {
        for (int coluna = 0; coluna < jogo.getMapa()[0].length; coluna++) {
            if(jogo.getMapa()[linha][coluna] >= 10 &&  jogo.getMapa()[linha][coluna] <= 21){
                casas[jogo.getMapa()[linha][coluna]-10] = new casa (linha,coluna);
            }
        }
    }
    return casas;
}
```

## I make heuristics total cost + distance from other houses unvisited

`casas_visitadas` are the number of visited goals, and `posL = row`, `posC = Col`. What I wanted to do is calculate the distance from where you are to the next uncompleted objective, + distance from this objective to the next objective... to the final goal.

```
    public double distanciaDasOutrasCasas(){
        double somaTotal = 0;
        int posL = linha,posC = coluna;
        for (int i = casas_visitadas; i < 12; i++) {
            somaTotal += Math.sqrt( 
                Math.pow( (double) (casas[i].linha - posL),2) + 
                Math.pow( (double) (casas[i].coluna - posC),2)
            );
            posL = casas[i].linha;
            posC = casas[i].coluna;
        }
        return somaTotal;
    }
```

## I check all possible movements

And I add them to the ArrayList. Here are the constructors:

```
  public ArrayList<Direcao> movimentosPossiveis(){
        ArrayList<Direcao> movimentos = new ArrayList<>();
        if (linha > 0) movimentos.add(Direcao.CIMA); // if isnt the first row add UP
        if (coluna > 0) movimentos.add(Direcao.ESQUERDA);//if inst the first col add LEFT
        if (linha < jogo.getMapa().length) movimentos.add(Direcao.BAIXO); // last row add down
        if (coluna < jogo.getMapa()[linha].length) movimentos.add(Direcao.DIREITA); // add right
        return movimentos;
    }

    public ArrayList<cell> permutaCelula(){
        ArrayList<Direcao> movimentos = movimentosPossiveis();
        ArrayList<cell> novasCelulas = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Iterator<Direcao> iterator = movimentos.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            Direcao D = iterator.next();
            switch (D){
                case CIMA:
                    novasCelulas.add(
                            new cell(this /*father*/, Direcao.CIMA /*direction from father */, custo_total /*total cost*/, linha-1/*row-1*/, coluna/*col*/, casas_visitadas/*goals visiteds*/)
                    );
                    break;
                case BAIXO:

                    novasCelulas.add(
                            new cell(this, Direcao.CIMA, custo_total, linha+1, coluna, casas_visitadas)
                    );
                    break;
                case ESQUERDA:
                    novasCelulas.add(
                            new cell(this, Direcao.CIMA, custo_total, linha, coluna-1, casas_visitadas)
                    );
                    break;
                case DIREITA:
                    novasCelulas.add(
                            new cell(this, Direcao.CIMA, custo_total, linha, coluna+1, casas_visitadas)
                    );
                    break;
            }
        }
        return novasCelulas;
    }

    public double convertePesoDoChao(){
        System.out.println(" L " + this.linha + " Coluna "+ coluna);
        int chao = jogo.getMapa()[this.linha][this.coluna];

        switch (chao) {
            case 0:
                return 200; //rock field, slowest field
    case 1:
        return 1;
    case 2:
        return 3.5;
    case 3:
        return 5;
            case 22:
                    if(quantidadeDeCavaleirosVivos() != 0) return Double.MAX_VALUE; // cant go to master without find all goals
                    finalizado = true; // found
                    caminhoFinal = converteCelulaParaMovimentos(); // converts cells movements 
                    return 0;
            default:
                casas_visitadas++;
                return 0;
        }
    }
public cell(cell pai, Direcao oPaiMexeuPraQualDirecao, double custo_total, int linha, int coluna, int casas_visitadas) {
        this.pai = pai; // father
        this.oPaiMexeuPraQualDirecao = oPaiMexeuPraQualDirecao; // direction from father
        this.linha = linha; //row
        this.coluna = coluna; // col
        this.casas_visitadas = casas_visitadas; //goals visited
        this.custo_total = custo_total + convertePesoDoChao(); // fathers total cost + field cost
    }
    public cell(int linha, int coluna) { //starter cell
        this.linha = linha;
        this.coluna = coluna;
        this.custo_total = 0;
        this.pai = null;
    }
```

## The heuristic

my heuristic is total cost + distancefromgoals

```
public double heuristica(){
    return custo_total *10 + distanciaDasOutrasCasas();
}
```

## Primary loop

```
if(!finalizado){
        this.jogo = jogo;
        colunaInicial = jogo.getColuna();
        linhaInicial = jogo.getLinha();
        casas = acharCasas();
        ArrayList<cell> franja = new ArrayList<>();
        franja.add(new cell(linhaInicial,colunaInicial));
        while(!finalizado){
            Collections.sort(franja);
            franja.addAll(franja.get(0).permutaCelula());
            franja.remove(0);
        }
    }
```

## The problem

It's taking too long, over three hours total, to find the way... any tips? I checked on the Netbeans profiler, and the problem is sorting the array.

My full code [is here](http://pastebin.com/zwHdb5nC)

obs: on full code, a game call the action move, and on the first call I need to find the best way, and save it, later I just pop the stack of movements

obs2: sorry my bad english, i used google translator on some parts

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'm guessing A* search algo (extension of Dijkstra's)

Comment: @hexafraction: ah, that makes sense. I thought he was referring to himself.

Comment: Yes, A* is a kind of dijkstra

Comment: No, A* is a graph algorithm that you can plug heuristics to act like Dijkstra. A* doesn't always return the same solution as Dijkstra

Comment: @cricket_007, if the heuristics are well designed for the problem both algorithms are complete and optimal, so the solution should be the same

Comment: @GuilhermeMagno if the problem is sorting the array you could try something different, like storing those values in a PriorityQueue that you can manage in a similar way. This yould be much more efficient than reordering the array in each iteration.